# Locked out of an old 2008R2 Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security

We just discovered another server with a database on it. The database is owned by a SQL account `SA`, with the `public` and `sysadmin` roles. The other login is `BUILTIN\Users`, with only `public`. I can only connect through this one. `SA` is `disabled`, and even if it wasn't, we might not know the password.

**Question:** Is there any way to `enable SA`, or create another sql login with `sysadmin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: start SQL Server with the -m flag from a local admin account.

Step-by-step instructions [here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out)